# Python read input lines through function call

Tags: python, file, text, input

My code below works perfectly to receive my input data (list.txt) and return lines between 2 and 5 to the screen.

```
def get_list():

    file = open('list.txt', 'r')
    lines = file.read().splitlines()[2:5]
    print (lines)

get_list()
```

However I am required to implement something where I can call the function like:

```
get_list()[2:5]
```

and this would print between lines 2 and 5 instead. Can anyone suggest a possible way I can do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Return the whole `lines` list from your function, then.

Comment: You'll want to close your file too. You can use `with` to automatically close the file when you're done with it

Comment: It's certainly _possible_, but I'm not convinced that it's actually a _sensible_ thing to do. :)

Comment: Do you **really** mean that `get_list()[2:5] ` should _print_ the selected lines, or do you merely wish it to _return_ those lines (eg in a list or tuple)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question comments, this is *not* a sensible thing to do, but here's how it can be done. To test this code I created a text file containing the integers 0 to 9, using the GNU coreutils command `seq`:

```
seq 0 9 >list.txt
```

And here's the Python code:

```
class AutoPrint(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        for row in self.data[idx]:
            print(row)

def get_list(fname):
    with open('list.txt') as f:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
    return AutoPrint(data)

get_list('list.txt')[2:5]
```

**output**

```
2
3
4
```

But *please* don't do crazy stuff like this in real code! My `__getitem__` method returns `None`; a proper `__getitem__` is supposed to return the selected item(s). And it shouldn't have crazy side-effects, like printing stuff. OTOH, I guess while you're developing the code it *can* be handy for it to print (or log) stuff so that you know that it's doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I understand this isn't a good thing to do will bear this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_list():

   with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
       lines = file.read().splitlines()
   return lines

print(get_list()[2:5])
```

Comment: @Shaikhar: This code will print all lines....not specified lines ie [2:5]

Comment: @mahendrakamble OP needs to call the function and then decide which lines to print.

Comment: This does work, I stupidly printed in my function rather than "returned" the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just return lines !

```
def get_list():

    file = open('list.txt', 'r')
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    return lines
```

Comment: That won't print the lines, though.